# print date of commits annotated tag point to

Tags: git

I have annotated tags that have been created days after the commit hash they point to.

In need to pretty print date of the commits, annotated tag point to (not the date the annotated tag itself has been created):

btw: I only need the year-month-day not more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### `git log`

```
// you can use any of the log pretty options
git log --oneline --graph --decorate
```

[image]

#### `git describe`

```
tag1
```

#### `git show`

```
$ git show tag1
tag tag1
Tagger: Al Blue <alblue@example.com>
Date:   Tue Apr 20 09:00:00 2011 +0100

commit 91a2b24....
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this answer was on : https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29497919/revisions

```
 git log --tags --simplify-by-decoration --pretty="format:%ci %d"
```